# TailwindCSS / Prettier adds space in @apply

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, prettier, tailwind-css

I've got Prettier setup to format on save my CSS files in VSCode.
I'm using TailwindCSS in one of my projects and using [the latest addition in 1.7](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases/tag/v1.7.0#use-apply-with-variants-and-other-complex-classes), prettier formats the file and adds a space after a single colon like so:

**Before formatting**

```
.container {
  @apply flex;
  @apply flex-col;
  @apply lg:flex-row;
}
```

**After formatting**

```
.container {
  @apply flex;
  @apply flex-col;
  @apply lg: flex-row;
}
```

Adding a space between `lg:` and `flex-row`.

Does anybody know how to fix this? At the moment I'm just ignoring CSS files to circumvent the issue.

### Solution

Prettier was not selected as the default formatter for CSS, only for TS and JS. Updating the default formatter for CSS to Prettier solved it.

Comment: I don't have described behaviour with `prettier@2.1.1` and default config. What version do you have and what config rules you use exactly?

Comment: I'm using 2.1.1 with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Comment: Well, I have the same, don't have such behaviour. Are you sure it's prettier fault?

Comment: Not reproducible either in playground https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEA6SsCGBLKcBOABMADpSGEACmADjQDYCehAZvXAB4DcZF1dTVuw4BaSPR7kqtBs3oBzJG04j8EAO6SAviAA0ICDRjZoAZ2ShM+NeoAKVhOZSZ66zI3P6ARvkxgA1nAwAMo0frjyyDD4AK5w+nAAtl5wACapaQAymFDyMZjycABiEPiJmDDGucggmDEwEHogABYwifQA6s3Y8KZhYHDBjj3YAG49jDVgpp4guKYEMLa+8uXILC4L+gBWphwAQr4BQcGYiXCZuHDrm-EguxzBEewAijEQ8Df0WyBh+Av4KYzJo0fC4GAdbCpGDNZAADgADPpQRAFh1fDQaqC4ADRtd9ABHd7wZaGJy1UwiPBpNJNfBwInYenLAprJS3fQLRLYKKxO6mZ5wN4fa7s753GCYLyQ6GwpAAJn00Rw9AiAGEIIk2SAcQBWJoxBYAFSlTg24v0oziAEkoBlYMEwGCjABBO3BGCMdhfBZaLRAA

Comment: Thanks for trying to figure it out. I have no idea where the issue comes from.
I just enabled the "format on save" option and it just does that. Which is pretty odd.

Comment: Okay I fixed it, prettier was not selected as the default formatter for CSS, only for TS and JS. Should have realised that. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: did you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

it is not prettier that adds extra space after colon : , it "esbenp.prettier-vscode".
to solve this problem change this settings in your settings.json file like this.
`"[css]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" },`

Answer (score 0):

In the `prettier` version `2.1.1` and above it works just fine.

Make sure you have set the `prettier` as the `default formatter`